# Get the difference between two dates show count as 1 if I select two dates as current date

Tags: javascript, datetime

I have the following fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/fNPvf/31895/

When I have the dates as follows `var firstDate = new Date(2008,01,12);
var secondDate = new Date(2008,01,12);` I am getting the alert as `0` I would like to display as `1` so can some one help me

Comment: From the 12th to the 22nd I'm getting 10, which is correct.

Comment: How would you expect the reuslt to be 1 when dates are same?

Comment: The full content of your question must be **in** your question, not just linked. Links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future, and people shouldn't have to go off-site to help you. Put a [mcve] **in** the question, ideally using Stack Snippets (the `<>` toolbar button) to make it runnable. More: [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: *"I am getting the alert as 0 I would like to display as 1 so can some one help me"* Um.... `+ 1`?

Comment: op is like i want 4-1 to be 2

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you want to show that something is 1 day long (with same dates), and if dates would be like

```
var firstDate = new Date(2008,01,12);
var secondDate = new Date(2008,01,13);
```

You would like to show it is 2 days long.

So why not just add 1 to diff ? (If I understed your goal correct)

```
var diffDays = Math.round(Math.abs((firstDate.getTime() - secondDate.getTime())/(oneDay))) +1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
    function change(){
       
       var oneDay = 24*60*60*1000;
    var firstDate = new Date(2008,1,12);
    var secondDate = new Date(2008,1,12);
    
    var diffDays = Math.round(Math.abs((firstDate.getTime() - secondDate.getTime())/(oneDay)));
//to avoid 0 & less and make it 1 at least 
//===========================================
    diffDays = diffDays <= 0 ? 1 : diffDays;
//===========================================
    alert(diffDays)
        
    }
```

```html
<input type="submit" id="byBtn" value="Change" onclick="change()"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want the difference of the same date, it will always be zero. Why shouldn't it?
Anyway you can check if the result is *0*, then set it to 1.

```
var diffDays = Math.round(Math.abs((firstDate.getTime() - secondDate.getTime())/(oneDay)));
diffDays=diffDays?diffDays:1;
alert(diffDays);
```